# Traefik can't load balance docker replicas

Tags: docker, traefik

I am trying to run `docker-compose up --scale apiserver=2` but Traefic can't load balance the api-server. I see the both apps on dashboard but traefic only load balance the first. When I check the logs I see that both of the nodejs apps are started

```
apiserver_1_cff59924db38 | Listening on port 3000. ContainerId: a2793ccb-daee-4a73-b4d0-6cbccb616cb9
apiserver_2_2164f88b7ed4 | Listening on port 3000. ContainerId: a92f516a-d66c-4672-b1b9-e0d8e182b46f
```

When I check Traefik dashboard, I see the below,

## backend-apiserver-dockertest

```
|Server                |Weight|
|----------------------|------|
|http://172.18.0.3:3000| 1    |
|http://172.18.0.6:3000| 1    |


Load Balancer
Method wrr
```

However whenever I hit `${API_NAME}` I only get a response from first API Server instance. Which gives me the UUID of first server `a2793ccb-daee-4a73-b4d0-6cbccb616cb9`

Here is my docker-compse.yml file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    traefik:
        container_name: traefik
        image: traefik
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
            - 8080:8080 #dashboard
        networks:
            - proxy
        environment:
            - DUCKDNS_TOKEN=${DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
            - ./traefik/acme/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
            - ./log:/var/log/traefik
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=8080
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${TRAEFIK_NAME}
        restart: unless-stopped

    apiserver:
        build: ./api-server
        networks:
            - proxy
        labels:
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${API_NAME}
            - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
            - traefik.docker.network=proxy
            - traefik.protocol=http
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=3000
        restart: unless-stopped

    website:
        container_name: website
        build: ./website
        networks:
            - proxy
        labels:
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAIN_NAME}
            - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https
            - traefik.docker.network=proxy
            - traefik.protocol=http
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.port=80
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    proxy:
        name: proxy
```

## traefik.toml

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
checkNewVersion = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[api]
  # Name of the related entry point
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: "traefik"
  #
  entryPoint = "traefik"

  # Enable Dashboard
  #
  # Optional
  # Default: true
  #
  dashboard = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  exposedbydefault = false
  watch = true

[acme]
  email = "email@address.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  acmeLogging = false
  [acme.dnsChallenge]
    provider = "duckdns"
    delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.mydomain.duckdns.org"
  sans = ["mydomain.duckdns.org"]
```

Comment: How are you checking this, with a browser?

Comment: Yes with a browser. I don't see any cookie though. I didn't set sticky session in the config. Why I still hit the same server, I really don't get it.

Comment: Test with curl instead. Also include your traefik.toml file in the question.

Comment: I added the traefik.toml file. Interestingly with curl it works. What is the reason though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traefik will load balance network connections to your application. However a web browser will maintain a persistent network connection and reuse it for future requests. The end result is you will see multiple clients load balanced, but a single web browser will keep hitting the same backend until that persistent connection is closed.

The reason curl works is because it closes the network connection every time curl exits, similar to the behavior of multiple clients.